# How does flexible and context-dependent Categorisation not imply fuzzy Category Boundaries?

Tags: semantics, prototype-theory

<sub>Source: p 283, *Understanding Semantics* (2 ed, 2013) by Sebastian Löbner</sub>

> [[Continued]](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/17666/5306) Likewise, the category VASE is
>   defined by the feature that vases are for putting cut flowers in. Thus, the
>   impression of a continuum of membership degrees between different
>   categories such as CUP and VASE is an artefact of an experiment that emphasized
>   the derivative feature of shape rather than the primary feature of
>   function. The test design also suggested that the categories tested should
>   be mutually exclusive. In fact, the same object can be used both for
>   drinking coffee and putting flowers in (a fact that was confirmed by
>   Labov’s results). When it is used for coffee, it is a cup, when it hosts a
>   bunch of flowers, it is a vase. Thus what the experiments really show is
>   that **[1.]** categorization is flexible and context-dependent  **[End of 1.]** because it is, for
>   things like cups, not primarily a matter of physical features; but **[2.]** they do not
>   prove that category boundaries are fuzzy **[End of 2.]**.

Please aid me to comprehend the distinctions and nuances between 1 and 2.
To me, 1 implies 2; so I am certainly neglecting something.

Comment: I don't think the quote you've provided is enough to really understand Löbner's argument. I'd need to also see how he talks about category boundaries.

Comment: You're quite right to be puzzled, Le. This does not strike me as illustrating much of anything, except possibly an unsuccessful attempt to justify the author's (or the translator's) idiosyncratic usage of terminology like "primary, secondary, flexible, category, context-dependent physical feature," and "fuzzy".